# Adding destination lat and lon to destinations variable distancematricx API Success and Fail

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

I'm trying to get the lat and lon from a Json encoded file for use as destinations for the distance Matrix API rather than add  var destinationA = new google.maps.LatLng(??.????, ???.?????);  multiple times.

I thought I managed it, as both ways seem to produce the same variable destinations when viewed, yet method two produces an error Uncaught TypeError: a.lat is not a function

This is method one which gives var destination a length of 7:

```
var destinationA = new google.maps.LatLng(13.7373393, 100.5558883);
var destinationB = new google.maps.LatLng(13.735132, 100.55611199999998);
var destinationC = new google.maps.LatLng(13.736953, 100.55819300000007);
var destinationD = new google.maps.LatLng(13.736244, 100.55694100000005);
var destinationE = new google.maps.LatLng(13.736166, 100.557203);
var destinationF = new google.maps.LatLng(13.738747, 100.55587700000001);
var destinationG = new google.maps.LatLng(13.733558, 100.56020699999999);
var destinations = [destinationA,destinationB,destinationC,destinationD,destinationE,destinationF,destinationG];
```

works great, will return the distances for each from a given centre point on google map.

Method two:
This is method Two which gives var destination a length of 1, which I am stuck on finding out why its a single length and not 7 as above:

```
var location_lat_lon = <?php echo json_encode( $properties_data ); ?>;
var  destinations = []
var first = true;

for (var i=0; i < location_lat_lon.length; i++) {
    var sep = first ? '' : ',';
    var lat = location_lat_lon[i].latitude;
    var lon = location_lat_lon[i].longitude;
    var destination1 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
    var destinations = [destinations+sep+destination1] ;


    first = false;
            }
```

which returns exactly the same result when viewing the variable destinations, yet this returns the error Uncaught TypeError: a.lat is not a function.

Any advice or guidance?
Is it not possible to pass destinations this way to the calculateDistances function?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: I'm guessing the values being read from a JSON file are probably strings.  The LatLng constructor expects floating point numbers.  Try `new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lon))`

Comment: Also if you're wanting to append each destination into your `destinations` array, use `destinations.push(destination1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var location_lat_lon = <?php echo json_encode( $properties_data ); ?>;
var  destinations = []

for (var i=0; i < location_lat_lon.length; i++) {
    var lat = location_lat_lon[i].latitude;
    var lon = location_lat_lon[i].longitude;
    var destination1 = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lon));
    destinations.push(destination1);
}
```

Comment: OMG.. Amazing, kop khun ka Duncan,,

Works perfectly now.. Thank you very much.